# How to filter / clone select box options with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following two select boxes:

```
<select id="project">
  <option data-person_ids="[75,76,77]">None</option>
  <option data-person_ids="[77]">Project A</option>
  <option data-person_ids="[75,76]">Project B</option>
  <option data-person_ids="[75]">Project C</option>
</select>

<select id="person">
  <option value="75">Person A</option>
  <option value="76">Person B</option>
  <option value="77">Person C</option>
</select>
```

How can I filter the `#person` options based on the value selected in `#project`?

This is a jQuery code snippet that a colleague came up with but I was unable to get it working because I am still new to jQuery:

```
$(function() {

  var $person = $('#person');

  $allPersonOptions = $person.children();

  $('#project').on('change', function() {
    var selected_project = $('#project').data('person_ids');
    filterOptions($allPersonOptions.clone(), +selected_project).appendTo($person.empty());
  });

});

function filterOptions($options, id) {
  return $options.filter(function() {
    return $.inArray(id, $(this).data('project_ids')) > -1
  });
}
```

Thanks for any help in this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your colleague gave you bad code.

First

```
var selected_project = $('#project').data('person_ids');
```

will return undefined since it is not on the select, it is on the option. It does not magically get the selected option's data attribute

```
var selected_project = $('#project option:selected').data('person_ids');
```

Next there is a random + in the code

```
filterOptions($allPersonOptions.clone(), +selected_project).appendTo($person.empty());
                                        ^^^
```

That is going to do a conversion, bad.

Next the filter code is looking for a data attribute

```
return $.inArray(id, $(this).data('project_ids')) > -1
```

There is no data attribute on that select's options. And the arguments are switched.

```js
$(function() {

  var $person = $('#person');

  $allPersonOptions = $person.children();

  $('#project').on('change', function() {
    var selected_project = $('#project option:selected').data('person_ids');
    filterOptions($allPersonOptions.clone(), selected_project).appendTo($person.empty());
  });

});

function filterOptions($options, id) {
  return $options.filter(function() {
    return $.inArray(parseInt(this.value,10), id) > -1
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="project">
  <option data-person_ids="[75,76,77]">None</option>
  <option data-person_ids="[77]">Project A</option>
  <option data-person_ids="[75,76]">Project B</option>
  <option data-person_ids="[75]">Project C</option>
</select>

<select id="person">
  <option value="75">Person A</option>
  <option value="76">Person B</option>
  <option value="77">Person C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works! Can you explain to a jQuery n00b what the `10` is doing inside the `parseInt` function?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: OK, that explains it very well.

Answer (score 1):

I have a version that reuses allPersonOptions (no need to clone) and only copies applicable options.

```js
$(function() {
  var $person = $('#person');
  $allPersonOptions = $person.children();
    
  $('#project').on('change', function() {
    var ids = $('#project option:selected').data('person_ids');
    $person.empty();
    $allPersonOptions.each( function() {
      var id = parseInt($(this).attr('value'));
      if ($.inArray(id, ids) != -1 )
        $person.append(this);
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="project">
  <option data-person_ids="[75,76,77]">None</option>
  <option data-person_ids="[77]">Project A</option>
  <option data-person_ids="[75,76]">Project B</option>
  <option data-person_ids="[75]">Project C</option>
</select>

<select id="person">
  <option value="75">Person A</option>
  <option value="76">Person B</option>
  <option value="77">Person C</option>
</select>
```